# Docker run error: could not create session key: too many links

Tags: docker

I have Debian 8:

```
Linux vps 3.16.6-042stab120.3 #1 SMP Thu Oct 20 18:18:21 MSK 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Docker:

```
Version:      1.12.3
API version:  1.24
Go version:   go1.6.3
Git commit:   6b644ec
Built:        Wed Oct 26 21:39:14 2016
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

problem:

```
root@vps:~$ docker run hello-world
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid header field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"process_linux.go:359: container init caused \\\"could not create session key: too many links\\\"\"\n".
```

How can i fix it?
Is it compatibile kernel?

Comment: I don't think it's related to your kernel version, I'm running docker under kernel 3.13 and works fine. Is that the only container or you have other containers running?

Comment: @Todea No running containers right now.

Comment: Maybe regardless the version, the kenel it not compatible due to some customizations (seems that machine is a cloud instance). Is updating the kernel an option?

Comment: @Todea yop, kernel version was faked and right version was older that I expected. Solved.

Comment: I rolled back your edit, because it is inappropriate here to add [SOLVED] to your title or an answer to your question in the question itself. If you found a solution and want to share it, do so by writing an answer in the space below provided for that purpose. It's totally acceptable here to answer your own question (see the [help/self-answer] for more details). If you don't want to share, then either wait for someone else to answer or delete your post.